# Como filtrar datos desde un documento js a otro

Tags: javascript, filtro

Tengo tres archivos JS. En uno de ellos tengo la data que quiero filtrar. En el segundo, haré todos los llamados al DOM y en el tercero, haré los filtros y otras funciones.

- Este es el código de la data, se llama BD.js

  ```
    export default {
    "restaurant": "cevicheria peruana",
    "year": 2018,
    "city": "Estados Unidos",
    "platos": [
      {
        "name": "ceviche",
        "price": "25.00",
        "type": "plato de fondo"
      },
      {
        "name": "tiradito",
        "price": "30.00",
        "type": "plato de fondo"
      },
      {
        "name": "arroz con mariscos",
        "price": "25.00",
        "type": "plato de fondo"
      },
    ]
  ```

  }
- Esto es el archivo JS dónde hago los llamados al DOM, se llama main.js

  ```
  import { BD } from './filter.js';

  import filter from './BD.js';
  ```
- Esto es el archivo JS que se llama filter.js dónde usaré la función filter. Aquí está mi problema, quiero filtrar los datos que tengo en BD.js en este documento que también es JS pero no me sale.

  ```
  export const BD =()=>{ 

      //ESTUVE PROBANDO Código

      let price = BD.filter(function(price){
          return BD.price === '25.00';
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Gracias por editar tu pregunta. Sin embargo, sigue siendo poco claro lo que necesitas. Intenta leyendo [example] para que podamos tener un ejemplo claro de lo que necesitas. recuerda darle formato a TODO el código. Saludos

Comment: Tu error es que confundiste `filter` con `DB`. Si te das cuenta `import { BD } from './filter.js';` debería ser `import { filter } from './filter.js';` ¿Lo ves?

Comment: Si, lo vi. Pero aún no me sale lo que busco. Solo quiero capturar los datos de BD.js (las propiedades del array 'platos') para aplicar el método filter en el otro archivo js.

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, tienes algunos errores en tu código.

Primero, tu archivo `filter.js` debería tener lo siguiente:

```
import data from './DB.js';

const price = data.platos.filter(function(plato){
    return plato.price === '25.00';
});

export const filtered = price;
```

Debes notar aquí, que para usar `filter()`, debes acceder a la propiedad `platos` del objeto que retorna tu `./DB.js`, ya que `filter()` se usa en **arrays**, no objetos. Puedes ver sobre filter en su documentación.

Posterior a eso, en tu archivo `main.js` sólo tienes que importar el filtrado:

```
import { filtered }  from './filter.js';


console.log(filtered);
```

Recuerda que no es un export por default, por lo que tienes que usar `{}`. Te recomiendo leer sobre named exports and default exports [aquí](https://javascript.info/import-export#export-default).